# Equivalent of loglog(MATLAB) to R

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a loglog graph but use the non-log labels. So instead of showing in x axis 1 (log10(10), it shows 10. I found the following solution. But that's too much work in my opinion. Is there anything equivalent to the Matlab function "loglog"?

```
plot(log10(x),log10(y),xaxt = "n") 
axis(1,at = c(log10(0.5), log10(10), log10(45),log(100)), labels = c(0.5,10,45,100))
```

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Pure programming questions like this are off-topic here, but this seems like a reasonable question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Is it frown upon to answer off-topic questions? I figured once you know the answer you may just post it...

Comment: @dariober: t is not frown upon, answering (mentioning it is really offtopic & votetoclose is a good option!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want `log='xy'` in the `plot` function call?

```
plot(1:10000, 1:10000, log= 'xy')
```

EDIT: Set `scipen` to prevent R from switching to scientific notation:

```
options(scipen= 99)
plot(seq(1, 1e9, length.out= 10), seq(1, 1e9, length.out= 10), log= 'xy')
```

Comment: This is better than writing log10(x) and log10(y), thanks! But still the labels of the x and y axis are in e-notation (e.g. 1e-02)

Comment: @Orestis See edit to prevent scientific notation

Comment: Yes, this did the trick. Thank you. Btw I found another solution using ggplot2 as well.          
    ggplot(aes(x,y)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    scale_x_log10() + 
    scale_y_log10()

Comment: @Orestis Ok good - learning ggplot is a good investment anyway.